# Disable drag on Google Street View

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I want to disable drag on Google Street View (essentially turning street view into a photo).  I've tried setting the following options in StreetViewPanorama, but none seem to work:

```
motionTracking: false,
motionTrackingControl: false,
fullscreenControl: false,
addressControl: false,
panControl: false,
zoomControl: false,
scrollwheel: false,
disableDefaultUI: true,
clickToGo: false,
draggable:false
```

So instead I've tried a little hack, by overlaying a hidden div like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/2gxqds1n/

using:

```
.prevent-dragging {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

and:

```
function initPano() {
  // Note: constructed panorama objects have visible: true
  // set by default.
  const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById("map"),
    {
      position: { lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326 },
      addressControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      },
      linksControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      enableCloseButton: false,
    }
  );
  
  //disable drag
 svDiv = $("#map");
 svDivHeight = svDiv.height();
 svDivWidth = svDiv.width();                           

 $('<div class="prevent-dragging"></div>').height(svDivHeight).width(svDivWidth).insertBefore(svDiv);
 
  
}

window.initPano = initPano;
```

It works, but if you start with the screen minimized and then maximize it (to resize/enlarge the streetview) the initial 'hidden div' doesn't expand.  So I need to listen for a resize/redraw event, but i can't find it?

I've tried:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'resize', function () { 
    console.log("resized");
});
```

But it doesn't fire.

Is there another/better way of achiving this?

Comment: If you want to *turn it into a photo* why don't you use the [Street View Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/overview)?

Comment: Hmm.  I didn't know about that.  Incidentally I've fixed my issues above here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvqbr2cp/.  But I'll look into the static API now.  Thanks.

Comment: Street View is not meant to be static. If you need it to be static, use the Static API as mentioned above. Any other solution would essentially be a hack. Also note that Static Street View is basically [half the price](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing#static-street-view) of the dynamic solution.